# Tough Pagination Script

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, pagination

Okay, so let me explain my situation then I will explain the code. The languages I am using are JavaScript, AJAX, PHP, MySQL. It is a very complicated code I will do my best to explain.

Scenario:
I created a script that fetches the projects stored in my database. Using javascript I have a function that says if my call to function "fetchProjectWebCall()" has a value within the parenthesis use it otherwise make start == 0.

Now using ajax request I send it to PHP. My script in php fetches all the projects stored in my database. When sending the response back I include an array called pagination which gives me the start point, end point, records per page, total records in db, pages needed to display these records.

```
if($result)
    {
        if(isset($request->data->start))
        {
            // Math for Pagination
            $start = $request->data->start;
            $end = $start + 9;
            $records_per_page = 10;
            $total_records = $result->num_rows;
            $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $records_per_page);

            $array = array();
            while($row = $result->fetch_array())
            {
                $user_id = $row["project_creator"];
                $creator_name = User::GetUserName($user_id);
                $array[] = new Project($row["project_id"], $row["project_name"], $row["project_description"], $user_id, $creator_name);
            }
            $array['pagination'] = new Pagination($total_records, $total_pages, $records_per_page, $start, $end);
            $response->data = $array;
            $response->status = Response_Status::$_SC_SUCCESS;              
        }
```

The PHP/MySQL/AJAX all work properly and generate the right results, so I am led to believe that the problem lies within the JavaScript. Using the AJAX response, I now want to display the records, starting from "start", ending at "end". Here is the JavaScript:

```
if(total < end)
        {
            for (var index = start; index < total; index++)
            {
                //Variables for Project Info
                projid = response.data[index].project_id;
                projname = response.data[index].project_name;
                htmlString +=   "<tr class='rowLight' height='30'> <td>"
                                + response.data[index].project_name
                                + "</td><td>"
                                + response.data[index].project_description
                                + "</td><td>"
                                + response.data[index].project_creator_name
                                + "</td>"
                                + "<td><input type='button' id='btnManageProject' value='Edit' onclick='manageProjectWebCall(" + projid + ");'/><input type='button' id='btnAssignGameToProject' value='Games' onclick='fetchProjectGamesWebCall("+ projid +");'/><input type='button' id='btnDuplicateProject' value='Duplicate' onclick='duplicateProjectWebCall(" + projid + ");'/></td></tr>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (var index = start; index <= end; index++)
            {
                //Variables for Project Info
                projid = response.data[index].project_id;
                projname = response.data[index].project_name;
                htmlString +=   "<tr class='rowLight' height='30'> <td>"
                                + response.data[index].project_name
                                + "</td><td>"
                                + response.data[index].project_description
                                + "</td><td>"
                                + response.data[index].project_creator_name
                                + "</td>"
                                + "<td><input type='button' id='btnManageProject' value='Edit' onclick='manageProjectWebCall(" + projid + ");'/><input type='button' id='btnAssignGameToProject' value='Games' onclick='fetchProjectGamesWebCall("+ projid +");'/><input type='button' id='btnDuplicateProject' value='Duplicate' onclick='duplicateProjectWebCall(" + projid + ");'/></td></tr>";
            }
        }
```

^^ this is where the display is created and ultimately where the issue lies. The condition if total < end is used because if the end value was 59 (generated from the php script which is start + 9, start would be 50 in this case) and the total records in the db was 52 (generated from php script) it would not display. The first for block demands that the array start at the index position "start" generated from the original request and go to total, granted the condition if total < end still exists

If total isn't < end it should go from index [start] to index <= end, incrementing by 1. The rest of the code works fine.

**The Issue/Problem**
Even though in the last block of code, for every other condition of total and end, the display should go up to and include the end value (starting from start which is 9 less then end). When total = end (example: total_records == 49, start == 40, end == 49, records_per_page == 10, total_pages == 5, generated from response data) it doesn't show the 5th page. It simply gets hung up at page 4 (start == 30, end == 39). This happens whenever total = end (39 records, end = 39 it won't show either)

My question finally is how come the script doesn't display the final page, when total=end? I have tried everything including changing the inequalities and including a total=end condition.

And another question, reviewing my code it possible to recode without adding any more conditions to the javascript (if total < end etc.). I don't want to change the script much because it works perfectly every other time.

Thank you for your time, and hopefully we can come up with a solution. If you need me to explain more please let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't be bothered working my way through your code. If your pagination code isn't working, why not use existing code from frameworks? Zend, Symfony, hell even Cake offers this...

Comment: the pagination works fine it only doesn't work when total records = the end variable, the script I created is extremely useful because it allows for many features such as back to search results etc...

Comment: What do you mean by 'gets hung up'?

Comment: @halfer: it just doesn't display records 40-49 (i have 49 records in my db) which happens to be page 5 (0-9 = page #1, 10-19 = page #2, 20-29 = page #3, 30-39 = page #4)

Comment: I'd tend to agree with Elias - you've made a sterling effort documenting your problem, but few people won't work their way through it. I'll not vote to close, as it's _probably_ answerable in its current state, but it would be good if you could trim it down to half its current size if you can. Also, consider writing some unit tests to work out which file/function contains the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding echo statements (or intermediate return values in JSON, for AJAX stuff) to see what is being wrongly calculated?

Comment: (Also: if you are directing comments to a particular person, use their name thus: @halfer, otherwise they won't be notified that you've said something. See the help block under this comment box!)

Comment: @halfer nothing is wrongly calculated, the JSON is all correct and does what its supposed to

Comment: @eliasvanootegem I have trimmed the code for you to take a glance at

Comment: Ah great, okay that narrows it down: if the JSON is returning correctly for the last page then your server-side response can be ruled out. I would next add `alert` statements into the JS to see where it is getting it wrong. I take it you've checked you're not getting an JS errors in your console?

Comment: @halfer if i have array index ending at 48 or array index ending at 50 it will work only indexes with a 9 at the end won't show (9,19,29, etc...)

Comment: OK, debugging time! I suggest you copy your JS to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), simulating the AJAX responses with hardwired JS objects (i.e. no AJAX/JSON) and then see how you get on. Share it in your question, and that'll give people something concrete to play with. Maybe there is a mistake in that string concatenation that you've missed, which linting will pick up, or maybe you have a JS error that you've not seen yet?